# error: ‘Integer Integer::operator<<(const Integer&, const Integer&)’ must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Integer 
{
    public:
    int i;

    Integer (int ll = 0, int k = 0) : i (ll) 
    {
        cout << "\nconstructor A\n";
    }

    Integer operator<< (const Integer& left, const Integer& right);
};

Integer operator<< (const Integer& left, const Integer& right)
{
    cout << "\ndsfdsfdsf : " << "===" <<  right.i << "\n";
    return left ;
}

int main () 
{
    Integer l;

    l << 5 << 3 << 2;

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the above titled error when I remove the keyword `friend` from the declaration of the << operator.
There isn't anything private here, so why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the operator declaration does not contain `friend`, the declaration declares a member, and a member has its class as its implicit first argument. With the two explicit arguments, this makes three arguments for a binary operator.

Comment: So, when a declaration IS a friend, what does the class think of it?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: A `friend` is for all purposes a normal function, but with special access rights. The behaviour is the same as if you had declared a free function `Integer operator<< (const Integer& left, const Integer& right)` above your class and made all your members public.

Answer (score 0):

The correct version should be like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Integer 
{
    public:
    int i;

    Integer (int ll = 0, int k = 0) : i (ll) 
    {
        cout << "\nconstructor A\n";
    }

    Integer operator<< (const Integer& right)
    {
        cout << "\ndsfdsfdsf : " << "===" <<  right.i << "\n";
        return *this ;
    }
};



int main () 
{
    Integer l;
    l << 5 << 3 << 2;
    return 0;
}
```